# Can you have "Not equal to" a range, in a condition?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

Is there a way to have an if-statement with the condition being `(x "not"<= 90)`?
Or is the only way to do that, using `(x <= 90)` in the `if` part and doing nothing as a result if that were true, then performing whatever needs to be done in the `else`? I should mention I'm    doing this in Java.

Comment: Anything wrong with (x > 90)?

Comment: Please, refrain from downvoting a perfectly valid beginner's question.

Comment: Are you kidding me... This question seems to be ultra ridiculous, and the author seems not to think about an answer for at least a nanosecond.

Comment: @EelLee OP is ultra-clever then, if it took him less than a nanosecond to think of the `else` idea.

Comment: I did not downvote, but this question demonstrates no research effort. It's more of a brainfart than a valid beginner question (in my opinion).

Comment: @jahroy I invite you to google the answer, without introducing any terms OP is not demonstrably aware of as applying to his problem.

Comment: @jahroy I have come to the conclusion that many beginner programmers have forgotten all their high school maths.

Comment: I agree, their's a debugger on most of the Java software for a reason.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that newbs find this site and use it to answer every quick question that pops into their head...

Comment: @thifofdeath I agree 100% except in this case, the debugger won't change you code for you.  Your IDE can refactor this BTW.

Comment: Let's not fool ourselves, what beginner started with using a debugger?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - If the OP is familiar with "_greater than_" it's not much of a reach to assume he should know about "_less than"_...

Comment: I realize I worded that question terribly...what I was really looking for was if it was possibly to invert an if statement `if(!(x <= 90))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can invert the statement with

```
if(!(x <= 90))
```

or just change it

```
if(x > 90)
```

Comment: @jahroy: definitely, I just wanted to illustrate how a statement can be inverted since that seems to be the biggest unknown here.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik And your IDE can do that for you as well.

Comment: +1 for demonstrating basic concepts and not mentioning an IDE.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yeah, you're right. I don't know why I thought it wouldn't I guess I was just over-thinking something simple

Answer (score 2):

The `!` sign is called the "*not operator*" or the "*bang symbol*".

It "*negates"* any boolean value that follows it.

You can use it in front of any expression that evaluates to a boolean value.

Example:

```
int a = 4;
int b = 5;
boolean isGreater = ( a > b );
if (!isGreater) {
    System.out.println("a is NOT greater than b");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you don't even need to know how to write this as your IDE can do this for you.  In IntelliJ if you write

```
if (x <= 90)
   doSomething();
```

and you press alt-enter on the if clause, you get an option to flip the condition and it will change it to

```
if (x > 90) {

} else {
   doSomething();
}
```

Similarly

```
if(x <= 90 && x >= 60)
```

can be refactored to

```
if (60 <= x && x <= 90)
```

and flipped to

```
if (60 > x || x > 90)
```

and refactored to

```
if (x < 60 || 90 < x)
```

without touching the code yourself.